# PHP Implode with array identifiers

Tags: php, implode

I want the PHP implode function to show me the array identifiers instead of just spitting put the array values.

```
implode(",", $_SERVER);
```

Comment: The array keys of $_SERVER?

Comment: how about just using json format, works with multi dimensional arrays and you don't heave to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @tripleb suggestions for good learning resources?

Comment: @tripleb i heeded your suggestion and utilized json_encode. problem solved, i have a list of what i need despite the curly brackets. but this may be helpful for other purposes

Comment: @d1sciple json format is more helpful perhaps then you now realise you can for example use it directly in javascript and have javascript render your data as you see fit, a table or a definition list etc....

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = [];
foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value) {

    $temp[] = "{$key}: {$value}";

}
echo implode(', ', $temp);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For key you can use :

```
array_keys($_SERVER);
```

or for values :

```
implode("','", $_SERVER);
```